How to replace result of 2 columns to add them into one? SQL
Need help combining these rows into one and combine their prices,
table name: customers



id
zip
price




1
100
9


2
200
9


A
300
1


B
400
1


3
500
9



if ID is not a number, replace ID = '0' and zip = '000' and combine their price into one
Result:



id
zip
price




1
100
9


2
200
9


0
000
2


3
500
9



id's A & B was replaced by '0' and zip by '000' and prices was added (1+1) from above table

One option is to use Case expressions and aggregation:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  tbl ( id, zip, price ) AS
    ( Select '1', '100', 9 Union All
      Select '2', '200', 9 Union All
      Select 'A', '300', 1 Union All
      Select 'B', '400', 1 Union All
      Select '3', '500', 9
    )

--      S Q L : 
Select    Case When ISNUMERIC(id) > 0 Then id Else '0' End as id,
          Case When ISNUMERIC(id) > 0 Then zip Else '000' End as zip, 
          Sum(price) as price
From tbl
Group By  Case When ISNUMERIC(id) > 0 Then id Else '0' End,
          Case When ISNUMERIC(id) > 0 Then zip Else '000' End

/*  R e s u l t : 
id  zip price
--  --- -----
0   000     2
1   100     9
2   200     9
3   500     9    */

See the fiddle here.

If all you want is to show it like that, you can simply use union all
select c.id, c.zip, c.price
from   customers c
where  isnumeric(c.id) = 1

union all

select '0', '000', sum(c.price)
from   customers c
where  isnumeric(c.id) = 0;

See also here
However,
If updating the rows in the table is what you are after, not just showing it combined, than you could do this in stages.
First sum up all the prices of nonnumeric id rows,
then delete the nonnumeric id rows,
and then add/update one row with the values you want.
See it in action in this dbfiddle here
declare @price int

select @price = sum(c.price)
from   customers c
where  ISNUMERIC(c.id) = 0; 

if @price is not null
begin
     delete from customers where ISNUMERIC(id) = 0; 

     update customers set price = price + @price where id = '0';
     if @@rowcount = 0
     begin
          insert into customers (id, zip, price) values ('0', '000', @price);
     end;
end;

